# Make use of a global array

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays

I want to use the values that I get from a request, but the response object is a local variable (an array). Therefore I create this global array:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var response = [];
```

as you see, right under the script opening tag, so it is global. Then in the function where I have the response I added this:

```
jsonResponse.forEach(function(element){
    response[element.size] = element.id;
});
```

And then added this, with the purpose to make use of the values that I've got in my global var from the response object:

```
getIdOfProductBySize: function() {
        var selectedIndex = document.getElementById('dropdown_options').value;
        for (var key in response) {
            if (key != selectedIndex) { 
                continue; 
            } else { 
                return response[key]; 
            }
        }   
    }
```

Doesn't work, so I started going step by step (of the order I add the new things) and I noticed that the script breaks after the 2nd thing that I add (where the `forEach` is).

Maybe I am not declaring the global variable correctly, or maybe I cannot access it this way, or maybe I don't assign the values to it in the correct way, I don't know, so I am asking if someone can give me a hint how to make use of all this working together?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var response = {key1: value1};

var i = 2;
jsonResponse.forEach(function(entry) {
   console.log(entry);
   response["key"+i] = entry.id;
   i++;
});


var index;
for (index = 0; index < response.length; ++index)
{
    console.log(response[index]);
    if(response["key"+index] !== selectedIndex)
      continue;
    else
      return response["key"+index]; 
}
```

Comment: Okey, that sounds good. But I need an array with a key and a value. Like that: `array('id' => 123, 'size' => 47)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
response[element.id] = element.size;
```

Try this one, i believe `element.size` returns the actual size of an element and is not what you want to use as index in an array.

Comment: Nope. It is a key of an index in the array, I am using it successfully on another place. Let's say the jsonResponse looks like that: `array('id' => 123, 'size' => 47)`. Therefore I want to assign the values to the `response` global var the same way.

Comment: Then you want to use them the other way around right, see my answer. Like using the ID as index in the array as well?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're going to need a two dimensional array.

Looks to me like your "key" value is undefined.

before:

```
for (var key in response) {
```

try:

```
var k=response.whatever;
```

If that makes sense?

Comment: Are you talking about the `forEach` loop or about the `for` loop in the 2nd function?